# ¿Cual es la lógica para determinar una puntuación comparando el resultado de 3 números al azar?

Tags: java

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

> Diseñe un programa que califique el puntaje obtenido en el lanzamiento de tres dados, de acuerdo a lo siguiente:
>
> - Seis en los tres dados, excelente.
> - Seis en dos dados, muy bien.
> - Seis en un dado, regular.
> - Ningún seis, pésimo.

Todo ya está programado, son 3 botones que generan un numero aleatorio a través de `Math.Random();` y luego otro botón recibe los parámetros impresos por los botones anteriores y los compara para verificar el puntaje. He probado con `if else`, sin embargo, mi lógica parece no ser la correcta. Adjunto la forma en como lo hice. Agradezco mucho de ante mano.

```
public String ObtenerPuntuacion(String N1, String N2, String N3)
{
    String respuesta = "";

    if (N1 == "6")
    {
        respuesta = "REGULAR";
        if (N2 == "6")
        {
            if (N3 == "6")
            {
                respuesta ="EXCELENTE";
            }
        }
    }
    else if (N2 == "6")
    {
        respuesta = "REGULAR";
        if (N3 == "6")
        {
            respuesta = "MUY BUENO";          
        }
    }
    else if (N3 == "6")
    {
        respuesta = "REGULAR";
    }

    return respuesta; 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esta es la idea. Contar la cantidad de "6"s y luego devolver el resultado.

```
public String ObtenerPuntuacion(String N1, String N2, String N3)
{
    String numero = "6";
    String[] respuesta = {"pésimo","REGULAR","MUY BUENO","Excelente"};
    int cuenta = 0;

    if (numero.equals(N1))
    {
        cuenta++;
    }

    if (numero.equals(N2))
    {
        cuenta++;
    }

    if (numero.equals(N3))
    {
        cuenta++;
    }

    return respuesta[cuenta]; 
}
```

Y es de notar que la comparación de cadenas debe hacerse con `.equals()`, no con `==`.

Comment: Muy sencillo + 1. Y vale la pena especificar que ajustastes la forma de comparar las cadenas para no caer en el error de OP de usar `==`, lo que no funcionaría bien.

Comment: ¿Puedes verificar que funcione @sstan y agregar lo que dices? no tengo un ide ahora mismo y la verdad no estoy seguro de que un arreglo se declare asi :P

Comment: jeje, ni me había dado cuenta lo del arreglo. En efecto, la sintaxis no era la correcta. Lo corregí.

Answer (score 3):

Una forma muy corta de solucionar el problema es:

```
public String ObtenerPuntuacion(String N1, String N2, String N3)
{
    String[] respuesta = {"pésimo","regular","muy bueno","excelente"};
    return respuesta [3 + N1.indexOf("6") + N2.indexOf("6") + N3.indexOf("6")]; 
}
```

El método `indexOf(String s)` devuelve -1 en el caso que el resultado **no** es 6, así subrtae del resultado ideal -1 para cada "6" que falta. Si el resultado de un dado es "6", el indice es 0, así no subtrae nada del resultado.

Comment: Interesante solución +1, pero habría usado algo como `return respuesta [N1.charAt(0) / 54 + N2.charAt(0) / 54 + N3.charAt(0) / 54];` que probablemente tiene muchas menos operaciones que [indexOf](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) :P

Comment: Tambíen tiene su creatividad :D No digo que mi alternativa es mejor, ni más performante (En java gracias a la optimisación runtime difícil de adivinar en todo caso), simplemente me aproveché de demostrar que siempre hay más que una forma de hacer las cosas.